# How to plot all columns of a dataframe?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Good afternoon !

Under R , i developed the following script :

```
  library("rootSolve")
    
  Sphere_1_pdim = function (x) return(sum(x^2))
    
  RMSprop<-function(objFun ,iter = 50000, alpha = 0.00001,lambda=0.2 ,start_init ){
  
  init = start_init
  
  gradient_1 <- function(init , objFun ) {
    
    p=ceiling(runif(1,min=0,max =length(init) ))
    result <- gradient(objFun, init,pert = 1e-8)    # vector of gradient / partial dérivatives 
    # print("gradient")
    # print(replace(result, sample(length(init),2), 0))
    # return(replace(result,p, 0))
    return(result)
  }
  
  x <- init
  
  # create a vector to contain all xs for all steps
  x.All = matrix(c(paste("X",1:length(start_init)),"objfun"),ncol=length(start_init)+1) 
  tmp<-rep(0,length(init))
  V=(1-lambda)*(gradient_1(x,objFun))^2
  # gradient descent method to find the minimum

  for(i in seq_len(iter)){
    
    V=lambda*V+(1-lambda)*(gradient_1(x,objFun))^2
    tmp = x - alpha*gradient_1(x,objFun)/sqrt(V)
    
    if ( !is.nan(suppressWarnings(objFun(tmp))) ) {
      x <- tmp
      
    }
    x.All = rbind(x.All,c(x,objFun(x)))
    
    
    
    # print(c(i,x,objFun(x)))
  } 
  
  # print result and plot all xs for every iteration
  print(paste("The minimum of f(x) is ", objFun(x), " at position x = ", x, sep = ""))

  # Here i should plot the x.All dataframe columns :

  plot(x.All, type = "l")  
  x.All=as.data.frame(x.All[-1,]) 
  print("x.All")
  print(x.All)
  dput(x.All)
  return(list(x,x.All))
}
```

Example of output :

```
       p=RMSprop(objFun=Sphere_1_pdim ,iter = 20, alpha = 0.01,lambda=0.2 ,rep(0.5,4) )

print(p[[2]])
            
[1] "x.All"
                  V1                V2                V3                V4
1  0.489793792738403 0.489793792738403 0.489793792738403 0.489793792738403
2  0.479794218064014 0.479794218064014 0.479794218064014 0.479794218064014
3  0.469836158529361 0.469836158529361 0.469836158529361 0.469836158529361
4  0.459887403385885 0.459887403385885 0.459887403385885 0.459887403385885
5  0.449941475647717 0.449941475647717 0.449941475647717 0.449941475647717
6  0.439997096792552 0.439997096792552 0.439997096792552 0.439997096792552
7  0.430054049875739 0.430054049875739 0.430054049875739 0.430054049875739
8  0.420112337792478 0.420112337792478 0.420112337792478 0.420112337792478
9   0.41017201167119  0.41017201167119  0.41017201167119  0.41017201167119
10 0.400233136231218 0.400233136231218 0.400233136231218 0.400233136231218
11 0.390295782982069 0.390295782982069 0.390295782982069 0.390295782982069
12   0.3803600292637   0.3803600292637   0.3803600292637   0.3803600292637
13 0.370425958630921 0.370425958630921 0.370425958630921 0.370425958630921
14 0.360493661256826 0.360493661256826 0.360493661256826 0.360493661256826
15 0.350563234797495 0.350563234797495 0.350563234797495 0.350563234797495
16 0.340634785238398 0.340634785238398 0.340634785238398 0.340634785238398
17 0.330708427713843 0.330708427713843 0.330708427713843 0.330708427713843
18 0.320784287730144 0.320784287730144 0.320784287730144 0.320784287730144
19 0.310862502424419 0.310862502424419 0.310862502424419 0.310862502424419
20 0.300943221952355 0.300943221952355 0.300943221952355 0.300943221952355
                  V5
1   0.95959183762028
2  0.920809966750635
3  0.882984063446507
4  0.845985695172046
5  0.809789326032179
6  0.774389780743497
7  0.739785943258098
8  0.705977505461846
9  0.672964316633562
10 0.640746253349907
11 0.609323192854345
12 0.578695007445931
13 0.548861563310546
14 0.519822719225405
15 0.491578326366735
16 0.464128227657637
17  0.43747225664385
18 0.411610237018144
19 0.386541981654287
20 0.362267291356257

Output of dput() : 

structure(list(V1 = c("0.489793792738403", "0.479794218064014", 
"0.469836158529361", "0.459887403385885", "0.449941475647717", 
"0.439997096792552", "0.430054049875739", "0.420112337792478", 
"0.41017201167119", "0.400233136231218", "0.390295782982069", 
"0.3803600292637", "0.370425958630921", "0.360493661256826", 
"0.350563234797495", "0.340634785238398", "0.330708427713843", 
"0.320784287730144", "0.310862502424419", "0.300943221952355"
), V2 = c("0.489793792738403", "0.479794218064014", "0.469836158529361", 
"0.459887403385885", "0.449941475647717", "0.439997096792552", 
"0.430054049875739", "0.420112337792478", "0.41017201167119", 
"0.400233136231218", "0.390295782982069", "0.3803600292637", 
"0.370425958630921", "0.360493661256826", "0.350563234797495", 
"0.340634785238398", "0.330708427713843", "0.320784287730144", 
"0.310862502424419", "0.300943221952355"), V3 = c("0.489793792738403", 
"0.479794218064014", "0.469836158529361", "0.459887403385885", 
"0.449941475647717", "0.439997096792552", "0.430054049875739", 
"0.420112337792478", "0.41017201167119", "0.400233136231218", 
"0.390295782982069", "0.3803600292637", "0.370425958630921", 
"0.360493661256826", "0.350563234797495", "0.340634785238398", 
"0.330708427713843", "0.320784287730144", "0.310862502424419", 
"0.300943221952355"), V4 = c("0.489793792738403", "0.479794218064014", 
"0.469836158529361", "0.459887403385885", "0.449941475647717", 
"0.439997096792552", "0.430054049875739", "0.420112337792478", 
"0.41017201167119", "0.400233136231218", "0.390295782982069", 
"0.3803600292637", "0.370425958630921", "0.360493661256826", 
"0.350563234797495", "0.340634785238398", "0.330708427713843", 
"0.320784287730144", "0.310862502424419", "0.300943221952355"
), V5 = c("0.95959183762028", "0.920809966750635", "0.882984063446507", 
"0.845985695172046", "0.809789326032179", "0.774389780743497", 
"0.739785943258098", "0.705977505461846", "0.672964316633562", 
"0.640746253349907", "0.609323192854345", "0.578695007445931", 
"0.548861563310546", "0.519822719225405", "0.491578326366735", 
"0.464128227657637", "0.43747225664385", "0.411610237018144", 
"0.386541981654287", "0.362267291356257")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Here i used a number of 16 iterations (`iter=16`) . **Each row  of the dataframe `x.All` represents one iteration of the 16.**

****For each row** , the **row index-1** represents the **iteration index**. The **last entrie** is the **value of the objective function**.**

I'm searching a way ( I prefer `ggplot2` ) in which i can plot the evolutions of columns ( from column `X1` to the `objfun` column ).

In this case , we will get 5 curves (in the same plot ) where the last curve is the evolution of the objective function `Sphere_1_pdim`.

I had tried to add ( before `return(x)` in `RMSprop` function ) :

```
  library(ggplot2)
  library(reshape2)

  x.All=as.data.frame(cbind(index=1:nrow(x.All[-1,]),x.All[-1,]))
  colnames(x.All)=c("index",paste("X",1:length(start_init)),"objfun")
  print(x.All)
  
  df <- melt(x.All ,  id.vars = 'index', variable.name = 'series')
  print(df)
  #create line plot for each column in data frame
  ggplot(df, aes(index, value)) + geom_line(aes(colour = series))
```

However , this had failed to plot the wanted curves .

I hope my question is clear for you !

Thank you a lot for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I have understood correctly.

This is your dataframe:

```r
df <- structure(list(X1 = c(0.489793792738403, 0.479794218064014, 0.469836158529361, 
0.459887403385885, 0.449941475647717, 0.439997096792552, 0.430054049875739, 
0.420112337792478, 0.41017201167119, 0.400233136231218, 0.390295782982069, 
0.3803600292637, 0.370425958630921, 0.360493661256826, 0.350563234797495, 
0.340634785238398), X2 = c(0.489793792738403, 0.479794218064014, 
0.469836158529361, 0.459887403385885, 0.449941475647717, 0.439997096792552, 
0.430054049875739, 0.420112337792478, 0.41017201167119, 0.400233136231218, 
0.390295782982069, 0.3803600292637, 0.370425958630921, 0.360493661256826, 
0.350563234797495, 0.340634785238398), X3 = c(0.489793792738403, 
0.479794218064014, 0.469836158529361, 0.459887403385885, 0.449941475647717, 
0.439997096792552, 0.430054049875739, 0.420112337792478, 0.41017201167119, 
0.400233136231218, 0.390295782982069, 0.3803600292637, 0.370425958630921, 
0.360493661256826, 0.350563234797495, 0.340634785238398), X4 = c(0.489793792738403, 
0.479794218064014, 0.469836158529361, 0.459887403385885, 0.449941475647717, 
0.439997096792552, 0.430054049875739, 0.420112337792478, 0.41017201167119, 
0.400233136231218, 0.390295782982069, 0.3803600292637, 0.370425958630921, 
0.360493661256826, 0.350563234797495, 0.340634785238398), objfun = c(0.95959183762028, 
0.920809966750635, 0.882984063446507, 0.845985695172046, 0.809789326032179, 
0.774389780743497, 0.739785943258098, 0.705977505461846, 0.672964316633562, 
0.640746253349907, 0.609323192854345, 0.578695007445931, 0.548861563310546, 
0.519822719225405, 0.491578326366735, 0.464128227657637)), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

1. First of all you need to reshape `df`:

   ```r
   library(dplyr)
   library(tidyr)

   df2 <- df %>% 
     mutate(x = 1:16) %>% 
     pivot_longer(X1:objfun, "variable", "value")
   ```
2. Now you can plot the data:

   ```r
   library(ggplot2)

   ggplot(df2) + 
     geom_line(aes(x, value, color = variable))
   ```

If your data are `character` use:

```r
x.All <- as.data.frame(sapply(x.All, as.numeric))
```

Comment: @Lenoardo , I obtain this error : `could not find function "pivot_longer"`

Comment: I failed to apply this code with `x.All` dataframe !

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the `tidyr` library. I edited my answer

Comment: @Lenoardo , how can i apply this with `x.All` ? I tried many times without success. (it seems like `pivot_longer` cannot recognize `x.All` columns names !

Comment: If `x.All` is the output you report, the problem is that it has both colnames (`V1, ..., V5`), and a line of characters (`X 1, ..., objfun`): that's not good. Use the dataframe that I report. It's like yours, but I took off `V1, ..., V5` and turned `X1, ..., objfun` into colnames

Comment: I already tried changing colnames with failure !

Comment: Sorry, but without seeing your data I can't know how to fix it. Edit your question with the output of `dput(x.All)`

Comment: i updated the post. The RMSprop function is an implementation of a stochastic optimizer. This means that `x.All` dataframe will change from  a run to another !

Comment: it doesn't matter if it changes. The important thing is that you report an output with dput. However, if `x.All` is a dataframe that has column names `V1, V2, V3, V4, V5` and has the form you reported you can use `colnames (x.All) <- c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "objfun")` and then use my code. If it doesn't work, I can't answer you again if you don't put the output of `dput (x.All)`.

Comment: The `dput()` of `x.All` had given number between double-quotes ( like characters. ex : "0.489793792738403" instead of 0.489793792738403 ). I think this is the reason why your code doesn't worked with my script !

Comment: I changed my answer to add `character` to `numeric` conversion. If you think it was useful, if you want accept it

Comment: This absolutely solved the pb. Thank you a lot for your valuable help and sorry for bothering you !

Comment: No bothering. See you next time!

Answer (score 1):

For this type of exploratory plotting, maybe consider `pairs`

```r
pairs(mydat, panel = lines)
```

[image]

Thanks to user Leonardo for the data +1

Answer (score 1):

We can use `matplot` from `base R`

```
matplot(as.matrix(df), type = 'l')
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = c(0.489793792738403, 0.479794218064014, 0.469836158529361, 
0.459887403385885, 0.449941475647717, 0.439997096792552, 0.430054049875739, 
0.420112337792478, 0.41017201167119, 0.400233136231218, 0.390295782982069, 
0.3803600292637, 0.370425958630921, 0.360493661256826, 0.350563234797495, 
0.340634785238398), X2 = c(0.489793792738403, 0.479794218064014, 
0.469836158529361, 0.459887403385885, 0.449941475647717, 0.439997096792552, 
0.430054049875739, 0.420112337792478, 0.41017201167119, 0.400233136231218, 
0.390295782982069, 0.3803600292637, 0.370425958630921, 0.360493661256826, 
0.350563234797495, 0.340634785238398), X3 = c(0.489793792738403, 
0.479794218064014, 0.469836158529361, 0.459887403385885, 0.449941475647717, 
0.439997096792552, 0.430054049875739, 0.420112337792478, 0.41017201167119, 
0.400233136231218, 0.390295782982069, 0.3803600292637, 0.370425958630921, 
0.360493661256826, 0.350563234797495, 0.340634785238398), X4 = c(0.489793792738403, 
0.479794218064014, 0.469836158529361, 0.459887403385885, 0.449941475647717, 
0.439997096792552, 0.430054049875739, 0.420112337792478, 0.41017201167119, 
0.400233136231218, 0.390295782982069, 0.3803600292637, 0.370425958630921, 
0.360493661256826, 0.350563234797495, 0.340634785238398), objfun = c(0.95959183762028, 
0.920809966750635, 0.882984063446507, 0.845985695172046, 0.809789326032179, 
0.774389780743497, 0.739785943258098, 0.705977505461846, 0.672964316633562, 
0.640746253349907, 0.609323192854345, 0.578695007445931, 0.548861563310546, 
0.519822719225405, 0.491578326366735, 0.464128227657637)), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: there is already a variable  ` x.All` ! , this data is just one example of what we could obtain after runnig !